# Accessing iTunes Gift Card Balance

Tags: ios, itunes-store

Is there a way to access a users iTunes Gift Card Balance and display it within a third party app?  I've been searching around but haven't found anything useful or anything that explicitly forbids it.

Comment: No, you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't supported. The entire amount of a gift is credited to your iTunes Store account and there is no way to look up users.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202359

Comment: You might want to quote the relevant portions from the apple page here, just in case it moves.